# SQL Server NULLIF does not work as expected?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code

```
Declare
@var nvarchar(5)
begin
    Set @var = ''

    Select 1 where @var = nullif(@var, '');
End
```

This does not output any result. Why NullIF is not working?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do/check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ISNULL`

```
Declare
@var nvarchar(5)
begin
  Set @var = ''

  Select 1 where @var = ISNULL(@var, '');
End
```

UPDATED...

```
Declare
@var nvarchar(5)
begin
  Set @var = ''

 Select 1 where @var = @var OR @var = ''
End
```

Comment: Hi Prashant16, sorry actually my question was not elaborate. I have to force null at the right side of the = sign when @var is empty. It works if I use "Select 1 where var is null;" But when I  use the = sign it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment you left, your question is a bit misleading.

I believe you're actually asking why the following statement does not work:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NULLIF(@var, '') = null
```

You can get this to work by doing the following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT 1 WHERE NULLIF(@var, '') = null
```

[ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) - When ON, the equals operator will not work and you have to specify `is null`. When OFF, you can use the equals operator against a null value.

--

This is a better approach to your problem, as ANSI_NULLs will always be ON in future SQL Server versions

```
SELECT 1 WHERE ISNULL(@var, '') = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equivalent. If the expressions are equivalent, NULLIF `returns a null value` of the type of the first expression.

[NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276840%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)